# Func and delegate: field or type

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm beginner in the use of pre-defined delegate `Func`. I thought that it is just a simple way to use delegate with return type. So, I used this snippet:

```
public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2);
public Func<object, object, int> FuncComparaison;

public static event Comparer OnComparaison;
public static event FuncComparaison FuncEvent;
```

I get an error in the last line indicates that `FuncComparaison` is a field used as a type. So:

1. What are the differences between the two declarations (first two lines)?
2. Why `Comparer` is considered as a type and `FuncComparaison` not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first one is delegate declaration. It creates a new delegate type. The second one is a public field of delegate type.
2. `Comparer` is a delegate and `FuncComparison` is a field, as stated earlier.

`Func<T1, T2, TResult>` is defined like

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T1, in T2, out TResult>(T1 param1, T2 param2);
```

so it's already a delegate and you later create a field and use it's instance.

Now you probably will understand why this line makes no sense:

```
public static event FuncComparaison FuncEvent;
```

Because `FuncComparison` is not a delegate type, but rather a name of the field declared earlier.

Think of `public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2);` like of a shortcut for defining a new type that is derived from `System.Delegate` that later needs to be instantiated and stored in some fields and you will probably avoid such confusions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2);` is a delegate which accepts two parameter and returns `int`.

where as

`public Func<object, object, int> FuncComparaison;` is a delegate instance.

here Func is a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hers Func is a shorthand for `public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2)`.

so how can you create instance of a instance ??

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public delegate int Comparer(object obj1, object obj2);
> ```

This is a type definition. It declares a new delegate type named `Comparer`, which requires a return type of `int` and two parameters of type `object`.

You recognise delegate type definitions by the presence of the `delegate` keyword (followed by a method signature declaration).

---

> ```
> public Func<object, object, int> FuncComparaison;
> ```

This is a field declaration. It declares a field named `FuncComparaison`, which has type `Func<object, object, int>`.

---

> ```
> public static event Comparer OnComparaison;
> ```

This is an event declaration. It declares (and auto-implements) an event named `OnComparaison`, which has type `Comparer`. Subscribing methods must have a signature compatible to that delegate type's.

You recognise event declarations by the presence of the `event` keyword (followed by a delegate type name).

---

> ```
> public static event FuncComparaison FuncEvent;
> ```

This is obviously supposed to be an event declaration, but invalid syntax, because `FuncComparaison` is used where a delegate type name was expected. However, it is not a delegate type, but a delegate-typed field. It's akin to doing the following:

```
int foo;
foo bar;  // syntax error because `foo` is used like a type, but is not a type
```

Answer (score 0):

Here,

- **FuncComparaison** is like a reference variable which will point to any method accepting parameters of object type & returning int.
  so syntax for this would be 
                                             **FuncComparaison=methodName**;
- **Comparer** is a delegate type, you need to create an instance of it to point to a method.
                         **Comparer** **delObj=methodName**;